# Validate a json field based on another field dynamically

Tags: java, jax-rs, bean-validation

I started to use validation framework `@Valid` to validate json request with jax-rs

Is it possible to validate a field against another field?

So this is how I wanna construct the request body:

```
@JsonProperty
private Integer peopleCount

@JsonProperty
@Min(value = 0)
@Max( value = peopleCount)
private Integer personId;
```

So when I pass

```
{
     "peopleCount":2,
     "personId": 4
}
```

it should throw an error

but `@Max( value = peopleCount)` does not work since it requires a constant value

please note that I'm trying to validate against the json request itself and not the values saved in DB

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom constraint like [class level constraint](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-class-level-constraints) for cross field validation.